# Put box around both p and blockquote element if they're both there

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have:

```
<div class='header'>...</div>
```

That contains multiple elements depending on the file.

In some files it looks like:

```html
<div class='header'>
  <p>
    ...
  </p>
 </div>
```

In others it might look like:

```html
<div class='header'>
  <p>
    ...
  </p>
  <blockquote>
    ...
  </blockquote>
  <h1>
    ...
  </h1>
 </div>
```

I want to create some css code that puts one box around all the `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements (not separate boxes around each) that exist in this .header (while not including the h1 element in this box). Is that possible or do I have to write separate css for each scenario?

Comment: can you share the visual output and more context?

Answer (score 0):

To make a box around the paragraph and block quote elements while leaving other sibling elements outside, create a `div` and put them inside that. Then add a border to that `div`:

```css
.header .container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <blockquote>Block quote</blockquote>
  </div>
  <h1>H1</h1>
</div>
```

If you wanted to do this without creating another `div` (100% CSS), you would need to do a lot more additional styling (that would be entirely dependent on the rest of your page) to have the borders around each element connect to form one big box.

Comment: I don't want everything inside the header to be in the box. If, for instance, there's an <h1> element after the <blockquote> element, I don't want that <h1> to be included.